# Putting ul, li and other code into external CSS stylesheets

Tags: html, css

I am coding a small website and I came across and error whilst coding.
I wanted to make a navbar so being me, I looked one up and found one. Unfortunately it used internal CSS which isn't my jam so I tried putting this (highlighted in quotes):

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nav.css">
    <style>
    "ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    }

    li {
    float: left;
    border-right:1px solid #bbb;
    }

    li:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
    float: left;
    }

    li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
       text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
    }

    .active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    }"
    </style>
</head> 
<body>
</body>
*/Stuff was here that the CSS corresponded to
</head>
<html>
```

Into an external style sheet that looks like this:

```
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}

li {
float: left;
border-right:1px solid #bbb;
}

li:last-child {
border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
float: left;
}

li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #111;
}

.active {
background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

But lo and behold it didn't work... Anyone know why?
(Forgive me if I messed it up, I'm new)

Edit:
Here is all the code:

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Evstotskian Alliance</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainpage.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nav.css">
    <style>
    ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    }

    li {
    float: left;
    border-right:1px solid #bbb;
    }

    li:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
    float: left;
    }

    li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
       text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
    }

    .active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    }
    </style>
    </head> 
    <body>
    <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="mainpage.html">Main Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="nations/nationlist.html">List of Nations</a></li>
    <li><a href="discord.html">Discord</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <h1>Welcome to the official website of the Evstotskian Alliance</h1>
    <h2>About the Alliance</h2>
    <p>The Evstotskian Alliance is a group of nations that strive to 
    help and benifits each other. Founded by Evstotska and Babilandia 
    the alliance was created in the Great Kieven War, after the war 
    Evan Wheeler decided no small nation shall be attacked by a giant. 
    Kiev is now an alliance leader along with Evstotska, Lakeland and 
    other nations.</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I want to put this part of the code:

```
    ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    }

    li {
    float: left;
    border-right:1px solid #bbb;
    }

    li:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
    float: left;
    }

    li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
       text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
    }

    .active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    }
```

Into an external file sheet that's already been defined in the code (navbar.css) however when I copy and paste into one it doesn't display the list as a navbar which is what the internal CSS is doing.
That's the thing I need help with.
Also I'm local hosting this so there's no domain
Thanks for all your patience

Comment: sorry but it seems unclear what are you looking for. So please explain more your issue ? what you want to do ?

Comment: Can you post a link to the website you got it from, or at least the whole code?

Comment: Have you flushed the cache, as external style sheets are cached? Have you used browser dev tools (F12) and its network tab to make sure the style sheet is found and loaded? Have you used dev tools to inspect the elements to see what styles are being applied and where they are coming from? "It didn't work" is more than a little vague, be as specific as you can. There is nothing inherently wrong with what you have done, we need more info.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing more of the code, but I suspect you may have made a mistake while linking your stylesheet. Double check the location and name of the external sheet and make sure you are importing it correctly. It could be a typo, you could have forgotten to link it, or it might be buried in a folder, for example. Good luck!

Comment: What you did 'should' Work. Have you Applied a link tag that points to the stylesheet on the server?